# Refrange in \ref Endash

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 1.\label{figa}}
\end{figure}

Figure~Sample Text follows
Figs~\ref{figa} \ref{figa,figb,figc} and \ref{figd,fige}.

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 2.\label{figb}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 3.\label{figc}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 4.\label{figd}}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 5.\label{fige}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Is it possible to redefine `\ref` in a way it is used in `\cite`, where single cite, 2 citations separated by "and" and multiple citations in endash?

For example:

```
\ref{figa} - Figure 1 - already coming correctly,

\ref{figa,figb,figc} should come as Figs 1-3

\ref{figd,fige} should come as Figure 4 and Figure 5,
```

I tried `cleveref`, but it adds a extra work to change the `\ref` coding to `\cref`, is it possible to do it without changing the LaTeX coding, please guide me.

Comment: Why can't you just automate replacing `\ref` with `\cref` or whatever? Regex's would work well here. I don't exactly understand why you already have code like `\ref{figa,figb}` or whatever. But, if you do, the replacement should be dead easy as you don't even need to worry about combining consecutive occurrences.

Comment: Redefining `\ref` is likely to break things you don't expect because it will not just be used directly in your document. It is very likely used by the macros you use from packages as well. If you don't care, you can always redefine `\ref` to be equivalent to `\cref` but you'd need to save the definition of `\ref` first and then patch the code from `cleverref`.